# Why does mplayer freeze when running from Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: cron, mplayer

I've been trying to use Scheduled Tasks and mplayer as an alarm clock, scheduling `mplayer /path/to/file.mp3` for my morning wakeup time, but whenever it reaches the scheduled time, mplayer freezes only a few seconds into the MP3. System Monitor indicates that it's still running and taking up most of a CPU core, it's just not playing audio.

The weird thing is that when I select "Run selected task," it goes just fine. (And in a terminal, which might be related.) It just doesn't work when it's running as a scheduled thing, whether it's as a recurring or one-time task. So it has to have something to do with the scheduler itself, and I don't know much about `cron`. What gives?

Comment: Is this because `mplayer` is quite verbose with it's output? Try commanding it to be quiet, or redirecting it's output to /dev/null

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, though I'm still not sure why that caused a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reading of key events from standard input seems to cause this, add following options:

```
-noconsolecontrols -really-quiet
```